# Always launch Windows Command Prompt as an administrator

Tags: command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10, administrator

In Windows 10, how do I always launch Windows Command Prompt with administrator privileges? Is there a keyboard shortcut to launch Commmand Prompt in such a way?

I am not looking to go to the Start button/Run command and then type something to open an elevated Command Prompt.

**Update:**

I've already tried this registry change but it didn't work:

[image: enter code here]

Comment: so you mean typing: windows key -> type "cmd" -> ctrl + shift + enter doesn't count as a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

To auto run CMD as admin each time it is simply clicked (without having to right-click or create additional shortcuts), there is an easy fix for this:

In the registry editor, navigate to "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" (If there isn't a Layers folder, you'll have to create one*)

Right click Layers, select New -> String Value. Set the Name of your new String Value to the full path to command prompt. (i.e. "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" without quotes)

Right click the new String Value and click "Modify...". Set the "Value data" to "RUNASADMIN" without quotes.

Comment: done as u recommended. still not working. using windows 10 enterprise

Comment: I also tested this out of curiosity, this did not work for me either.